# Does exporting a function creates a singleton of the function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, singleton

I am trying to implement a abstraction on top of my API. I need to have a single instance of the axios client so I can intercept requests at a later stage. With the code below I try to reuse the same instance. Does the code below guarantee that there is only one axios client when I am importing the functions (i.e. authenticate) inside my view layer? If so, why?

**index.ts**

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080';
export const axiosClient = axios.create();
```

**session.ts**

```
import {axiosClient, baseUrl} from './index'
import {User} from "../_models/user";

interface AuthenticateResponse {
    token: string,
    user: User
}

export function authenticate(username: string, password: string) :Promise<User> {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.set('username', username);
    formData.set('password', password);

    return axiosClient.post(baseUrl + '/login', formData)
        .then(resp => {
            let authResp: AuthenticateResponse = JSON.parse(resp.data);

            localStorage.setItem('token', authResp.token);
            return authResp.user
        })
}
```

Comment: What you export is what you get - in your case you export instance of an object which will be same instance in every other import (so a singleton). Other option is to export a function that creates your object and that way you'd avoid singleton, but you'd have to create instance after every import because you'd be importing "factory".

Answer (score 0):

If your `index` module isn't imported from two different locations for some reason, you should be fine because Modules are loaded based on their file name. If `require` resolves to the same file name it will return the same module and the code should be executed only once and the singleton should be instantiated only once.

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_caching_caveats

Most frontend frameworks provide mechanics to deal with singletons though. Some examples:

https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#provider-and-inject

I personally would not rely on `require` to create singletons. Best to use either the web frameworks mechanics or to tweak the architecture in some way that the object that is supposed to be a singleton is passed through the hierarchy.

It might be an idea to pass a function to `authenticate` that gets executed after the request returns or whenever you need it to be.